# Как производить js действия в CURL?

Tags: curl, php, ajax, javascript

Дело в том, что нужно разобрать одну инфу с сайта, а инфу можно получить, нажав на кнопку "Просмотр". В начале я подумал - "легко"! Но не тут-то было (инфа вытаскивалась ajax-ом, когда отключил в браузере js, работать кнопка перестала). Я начал искать обработчик запроса, чтобы напрямую выполнять запросы со своего сайта, но там, видимо, защиты на внешние запросы, ибо не получилось. Подскажите, пож-та, как мне быть? Может есть какие-то методы js воспроизводить? Хотя я и понимаю, что это клиентский язык... Но всёже вдруг...

Comment: Способов - как вы хотите - нет! Только разбираться в логике скрипта, изучать, подделывать...

Comment: Попробуйте подцепить curl'ом - методы-то одни и те же. Принцип работы: ajax запрос на свой сервер, curl делает запрос на чужой сервер и тянет нужную инфу. Но вот на счет быстродействия я не уверен...

Comment: Хотите сказать, что нужно отправить на ajax обработчик curl-запрос c подделанными заголовками (тем самым подделаю $_SERVER)? Ну а как угадать какие заголовки должны отправляться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотреть в FireFoxe-е в FireBug-е в закладке Net какие запросы выполняются, и подумать как это можно использовать

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно скопировать просмотр в буфер обмена и потом сохранить
2. если есть старый офис, то можно отладчиком MSE открыть сайт и посмотреть по каждой операции до просмотра что делает и взять содержимое из значений переменной
3. Для Windows можно через отдельный js файл

-

```
ie=ActiveXobject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.visible=true;
ie.Navigate("http://url...");
while(ie.ReadyState<4)WScript.Sleep(300);
info=document.getElementById("ID");
```

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно, о чём Вы(